# Statsmodels Examples, where are they?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

http://nipy.bic.berkeley.edu/nightly/statsmodels/doc/html/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.wald_test.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.wald_test indicates there are examples to look at, the only place these examples would be is http://nipy.bic.berkeley.edu/nightly/statsmodels/doc/html/examples/index.html. Any clues as to where the example for the wald statistic is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all examples directly in [Github](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/tree/8709f007cac9e1f8b0263ee251892e8096148e52/statsmodels/examples). the only example I found using the `wald_test` was [`ex_ols_robustcov.py`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/8709f007cac9e1f8b0263ee251892e8096148e52/statsmodels/examples/ex_ols_robustcov.py).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this docstring was copy-pasted from the `t_test` and `f_test` method, but the examples weren't. You can see those methods for examples.